# Printing properties from an array of hashes to an erb in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreach, erb

I'm new to Ruby on rails and am a bit confused. I have an array of hashes that I parsed through json in a helper:

```
a = [{"desc"=>"testdesc1", "owner"=>{"url"=>"https://www.example1.com"},
{"desc"=>"testdesc2", "owner"=>{"url"=>"https://www.example2.com"}]
```

and now I want to display it in my **.erb** like this:

```
<h3>name (with link to url)<h3>
<div>desc</div>
```

I cannot even begin with the first step, which is to parse the array. When I try different variations of the **each** loop they simply print out the full array.
Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
array.each do |entry|
    <h3><a href="#{entry["owner"]["url"]}"> entry["name"] </a></h3>
    <div>entry["desc"]</div>
end
```